# It doesn't return anything

Tags: angularjs

It doesn't work why?
this is html
ng-repeat doesn't work . I can't understand what's wrong with it . I checked everything but it still the same thing and it looks like this post is mostly code so i need to add more words to here to share this with you guys.I think this information is sufficient

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="telebe">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>AngularJS Practice</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="BodyController as bc">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="telebe in telebeler" >
                <td>
                    {{telebe.ad}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{telebe.soyad}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{telebe.age}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is app.js

```
app = angular.module("telebe",[ ]);

app.controller("BodyController",function(){
    this.telebeler = [{ad:'Murad',soyad:"Ramazanli",qrup:'b',id:5,age:22},{ad:'Sultan',soyad:"Esgerov",qrup:'a',id:2,age:14},{ad:'Nazim',soyad:"Memmedov",qrup:'c',id:1,age:23},{ad:'Leyla',soyad:"Semedova",qrup:'b',id:3,age:24}];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing `telebeler` to `bc.telebeler`:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="telebe in bc.telebeler track by $index" >
        <td>
            {{telebe.ad}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{telebe.soyad}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{telebe.age}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z619bIdwE154sbjEVThn?p=preview)**, its working.

simply add a `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` refer to the update above.
See this **[error reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)** to understand it more

Comment: can you write down the error? its working on my end see the plunker i've updated.

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=telebe%20in%20bc.telebeler&p1=string%3Aa
    at Error (native)

Comment: check my update, simply add `track by $index` in your ng-repeat

Comment: Thanks for your effort i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot passing $scope parameter. Replace `this` with `$scope` while assigning `telebeler` value

```
app.controller("BodyController",function($scope){
        $scope.telebeler = [{ad:'Murad',soyad:"Ramazanli",qrup:'b',id:5,age:22},{ad:'Sultan',soyad:"Esgerov",qrup:'a',id:2,age:14},{ad:'Nazim',soyad:"Memmedov",qrup:'c',id:1,age:23},{ad:'Leyla',soyad:"Semedova",qrup:'b',id:3,age:24}];
    });
```

Comment: Not sure why its not working for you. working jsbin can be found here: http://jsbin.com/manobewu/1/edit